# extracting values from fasta dotplot in R

Tags: r

I have a dotplot (using dotPlot() from seqinr package) of 2 fasta sequences and I need to extract some values (x,y) from the plot.

I tried to use identify(), which works with "normal" plots and gives back a vector with the clicked values from the plot, but it doesn't work on the dotPlot.

Any possible solution would be welcome, including using dotter in shell or python.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code that was used to create the plot, or just an image file?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, the function I used is this one http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/software/SeqinR/SEQINR_CRAN/DOC/html/dotPlot.html

Comment: It looks like an image file....but i'm not sure

Comment: OK, are you clicking on a plot in an R figure window or are you clicking on a JPEG or PNG that you opened from your file system.  And do you have access to the code that was used to create the plot, or did someone else creat it for you?

Comment: Yes I'm clicking on the plot in the R figure window using identify() function.
the plot is created by the dotPlot() function of seqinr package, and so I only submit the imput character files that I want to align.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotPlot` uses `image` to draw its points. So there are no "points" to recognize when `identify` is called. If you plot the two sequences and use the same logic as `dotPlot` you will have more success.

```
seq2 <- seq1 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 100, repl=TRUE), collapse="")
for ( i in sample(1:100, 20) ) { seq2 <- 
  paste0(substr(seq2, 1, i-1), "Z", substr(seq2, i+1, nchar(seq2) ) )}
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100)); 
for ( i in 1:100 ) { 
           if(substr(seq1,i,i)==substr(seq2, i,i) ){ points(i,i)}
pts <- identify(1:100, 1:100, n=5)
```

Comment: Your script works, but I need to automatize a repetitive motive search, so I'm not looking for only the diagonal but also the small alignment inside the sequence. For example something like that( http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/molkit/dnadot/retrodot.gif)

I was thinking something like
seq1 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 100, repl=TRUE))

seq2 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 100, repl=TRUE))

x=data.frame(matrix(0,100,100))

for (i in 1:100) for (j in i:100) if(seq1[i]==seq2[j]) x[i,j]=1

and then plot it

Comment: The Z was just a non-matching letter that I inserted. I wanted to have more matching than non-matching. I don't do genetics and was just trying illustrate the capacity of `identify` to "work" something vaguely like what I was seeing in the `?dotPlot` example. I wouldn't have `paste`-d if I were going to use a dataframe to hold the residues.

Comment: It's almost what i need, i need to compare any position of seq1 to any position of seq2, i'll use your function and i'try to add another for loop

Comment: Perhaps 'outer' on strsplit with split = "". I'm on the road now and you had 't provided a workable data object. Maybe ask a new question with data?

Comment: Ok i will, it was my first question here

Comment: the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706002/r-doplot-coordinates-locator

Answer (score 1):

Finally thanks to DWin I got what I needed

```
seq1 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 100, repl=TRUE), collapse="")
seq2 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 100, repl=TRUE), collapse="")

plot(NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100),type="p"); 
for ( i in 1:100 ) 
    {  for ( j in 1:100 ) 
    {  if(substr(seq1,i,i)==substr(seq2, j,j) ) points(j,i)
       }}
pts <- identify(1:100, 1:100, n=5)
```

or also

```
l=100
seq1 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), l, repl=TRUE)) 
seq2 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), l, repl=TRUE)) 
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100),type="p"); 
for (i in 1:l) for (j in i:l) if(seq1[i]==seq2[j]) points(j,i)
pts <- identify(1:100, 1:100, n=5)
```

The only problem is that it's quite slow and the "points" size in the plot is to big, all of them overlap each other and if I align long sequences it won't be able to recognize any of them