# R Doplot() coordinates locator()

Tags: r, plot

I drew a dotplot (using dotPlot() from seqinr package) of 2 fasta sequences and I need to extract some values (x,y) from the plot.
The Dotplot() output is an image
A generic dotplot maybe be this one

[image]

**I need for example the values of start & end of the local alignment which are represented by the purple lines**
so here an example

```
l=30
seq1 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), l, repl=TRUE)) 
seq2 <- paste(sample(c("A","G","T","C"), l, repl=TRUE)) 

dotPlot(seq1,seq2, wsize = 2, wstep = 1, nmatch = 2, col = c("white", "green"), xlab = deparse(substitute(seq1)), ylab = deparse(substitute(seq2)))
```

[image]

```
  locator(n=2, type="p")
$x
[1] 27.18720 31.23263

$y
[1] 20.45222 24.65726
```

So I want exactly the position of the 2 circled points,and as you can see the **`locator()`** gives decimal value .
I may use **`ceiling()`** or **`round()`** but i maybe get back an approximation error

I need the integer value of the point I clicked on, basically the nearest point to the place

Would be perfect to use **`identify()`**, which works with "normal" plots and gives back a vector with the closest plotted value to your "click", but it doesn't work on the dotPlot() output (the problem seems to be that it doesn't work on image output as locator() )

Any possible solution would be welcome, including using dotter in shell or python. Thanks

Comment: you should just `set.seed` to make your example completely reproducible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the set.seed function, I'm gonna try now!
what I need it's just to know if I can get the coordinates of 2 random points (circled in black) that I click on the plot without any decimal values and approximation...

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned `Identify` doesn't work since it need a plot not an image. Maybe a solution is to call `image` after `plot(type="n",..)` but this need to change the `dotPlot` function source code. Another elegant solution is to use `lattice` package and `panel.identify` the grid equivalent  of `identify`.

Here an example, where I select some points ( 6 -> 15):

```
library(lattice)
dotplot(y~x,data.frame(x=letters,y=letters))
trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1)
> panel.identify()
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I need to use DotPlot() or something similar because I need to find repeated or inverted domain  which don't appear  in the main diagonal but elsewhere in the plot.
I mean something like this pic http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/molkit/dnadot/retrodot.gif
So should I contact the writer of dotPlot() function and ask to implement it as suggested? :-)

Comment: @mirkuz honestly I am lost with your picture. I add it to your original question maybe you can add some explanations to clarify what do you want to do. Also it is better to provide some data to reproduce the plot.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't upload pictures because I'm new here. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `evolvedmicrobe/dotplot` on github

https://github.com/evolvedmicrobe/dotplot/blob/master/R/plotters.R

It provides `mkDotPlotDataFrame`. With this you can better get coordinates between matches, like with `identify`.